# Is it necessary to forward ports for a PS3?

Tags: networking, ps3

I bought a PS3 a few days ago and wanted to know is it necessary to forward ports on my router for the PS3? I don't know much about PS3 networking so please let me know what information you would need and I'll provide it.

EDIT: What made me wonder was the fact that everywhere I look everyone says you should forward ports for your Bittorrent client. I've never had a problem using uTorrent without forwarding ports but I do it anyways. I don't have a problem using my PS3 online but didn't know if it would improve my connection or help in some unknown way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your router supports UPnP, which almost everything in the last 4-5 years does, then you are fine, as the PS3 supports UPnP as well.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not necessary, unless your PS3 is modded as some sort of server, and it is providing a service to users outside your network. If it isn't modded and you're just playing regularly it should work fine due to UPnP as MarkM mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Our PS3 is connected to the router here, and we never changed any settings to the Router to make it work.

So no you don't need to open any ports.

And this question is probably gonna get closed since it's a game related question.

Answer (score 0):

I put my PS3 into DMZ (De militerized Zone) sicne it is a console it does not have the same protocols and active services as a computer so theres no worries of hackers or viruses(they just would not know what to do ) in DMZ mode your ps3 will have UNRESTRICETED access to the internet giving the BEST experince...

Good LUCk

Comment: Just because an exploit for a PS3 doesn't exist doesn't mean it can't. It is a network enabled device, and exposing it needlessly is a risk. It's probably a very small risk, but a risk all the same, there is no benefit to doing this if your router has UPnP and if it has a DMZ setting, it most likely has a UPnP setting.